# Sumar y promediar en días un terminó entre dos fechas

Tags: mysqli

Tengo esta duda respecto de una consulta mysql, lo que necesito es que me traiga todos los resultados que cumplan una condición, adicionalmente que calcule en días la diferencia entre esos dos fechas y luego sume todos los dias, para yo calcular el promedio de la suma de los dias.

he probado haciendolo asi:

```
select count(*) AS Cantidad25, sum(timestampdiff(DAY, fcres, agd_start)) as total25 from mgivc_sol WHERE estado=4
```

Con cantidad25 determinó el total de registros que cumplen la condición, posterior con total25 deberia darme la suma de los días promediados que en resultados me da 52, pero realmente debería ser 36, es decir estoy haciendo algo mal.

La idea es que para poder hacer el promedio solo debería dividir la cantidad de registros (cantidad25)/(total25), pero como ya lo mencione no me esta haciendo bien la operación respecto de total25.

Alguien me puede dar alguna luz por favor!

POS: ambos campos (fcres y agd_start) estan en formato date en mysql (EJ: 2019-03-25)

Comment: No estás haciendo la operación de división que refieres. Intenta así: `select count(*) AS Cantidad25, count(*) / sum(timestampdiff(DAY, fcres, agd_start)) as total25  from mgivc_sol WHERE estado=4`